# Read txt file into dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am having problems trying to read this *txt* file into dictionary in python. How can do it?

`NAMES  MARKS
Lux     95
Veron   70
Lesley  88
Sticks  80
Tipsy   40
Joe     62
Goms    18
Wistly  35
Villa   11
Dentist 72
Onty    50`

Comment: Hi @Ross and welcome to StackOverflow ! Please make sure you took the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), then edit your question to show us what you have tried. We cannot help you solve this problem if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file using the line:

```
with open('<filename>') as f:
```

This will set the variable called f to the file.
you could try using the split function

```
with open('<filename>') as f:
    dict = {}
    for line in f:
        part_one, part_two = line.split(" ")
        dict[part_one] = part_two

    print(dict)
```

i believe this should work if each record in your file is on a new line IE:

```
NAMES MARKS
Lux 95
Veron 70
Lesley 88
Sticks 80
Tipsy 40
Joe 62
Goms 18
Wistly 35
Villa 11
Dentist 72
Onty 50
```

Comment: `with open('<filename>') as f:` is better because it will close the file.

Comment: i have now read the information to a file.Now i need to write the ouput of it to a new file after few computations.
    c=sum(int(Results[x]) for x in Results)
    r=c/12
    d=len(Results)
    F=max(Results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    u=min(Results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    print ("Number of entries are",d)
    print ("Student with HIGHEST mark is",F)
    print ("Student with LOWEST mark is",u)
    print ("Avarage mark is",r)
    Results = [ (v,k) for k,v in Results.items() ]
    Results.sort(reverse=True)
    for v,k in Results:
    print(k,v)

Comment: I would recommend looking at some documentation for writing to files, this should do what you need. "http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html"